# Why my previous button doesn't work?

Tags: android, sqlite

I make application and I have a problem with database again. 
I made two buttons - previous button and next button. 
Next button is work, but after click previous button program doesn't diplay record in textview. Why? 
First I click nest button all work then I click previous button and "cursor" go to previous record but doesn't display record in textview.

I solved my problem. 
I deleted methods: getNextdata() and getPrevData.

Now my code is:

Galeria.java:

```
public class Galeria extends Activity {

    public static long record = 1;
    PrzyslowiaArabskie info = new PrzyslowiaArabskie(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galeria);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        info.open();
        int irec = info.policz_rec();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " ilość przysłów w bazie " + irec, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String data = info.getData(record);
        info.close();
        tv.setText(data);


        Button bNastepny = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        bNastepny.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                info.open();
                record++;
                String data = info.getData(record);
                info.close();
                tv.setText(data);

                }
        });
        Button bPoprzedni = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        bPoprzedni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                info.open();
                record--;
                String data = info.getData(record);
                info.close();
                tv.setText(data);

                }
        });
    }
}
```

My method in DB Helper class:

```
public String getData(long record) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        record = Galeria.record;
        String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_PRZYSLOWIE};
        Cursor c = myDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, columns, KEY_ID + "=" + record, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
             c.moveToFirst(); 
             String data = c.getString(1);
             return data;
    }
        return null;


}
```

And my all buttons (next and prefious) work. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without running your code, are you sure that you didn't forget to put:

`info.open();`

and

`info.close();`

in your previous button's onclick listener?

such as:

```
Button bPoprzedni = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prev);
    bPoprzedni.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            info.open();
            record--;
            String data = info.getPrevData(record);
            info.close();
            tv.setText(data);

        }
    });
```

==================================

if that doesn't solve the problem, does your logcat indicate any errors? if not, are you absolutely sure that you are retrieving a string from your `getPrevData(record)` method? you can check this by doing something like:

```
String data = info.getPrevData(record);
Log.d("bPoprzedni", data);
```

and if `data` is not showing in LogCat, then you know you're not getting it from the database correctly.

if `data` is showing up in LogCat, then you narrowed the problem down, and we can help you with that part easily :)

Comment: I added message from Logcat.

Comment: Above message from Logcat id If I run app in Android SDK 8. If I run app on SDK API Level 16 LogCat doesn't show error but previous button doesn't work.

Comment: @Tomeksss Sorry, i didn't understand. The fix (`info.open()` and `info.close()`) still does not work for SDK API level 16? It still crash? even after you put in `info.close()`?

Comment: No, the fix work, My button "bNastępny" (next) work. I don't know why after click previous button program doesn't display previous record from database.

Comment: @Tomeksss Proszę przeczytać ten http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940308/im-getting-a-database-object-not-closed-exception-in-sqlite-android-but-im

Comment: @Tomeksss Czy możesz zaktualizować Pytanie numer linii, które widzisz błąd?

Comment: I think that, error is getPrevdata() method. Do you know how to get and display previous and next record from database after click button? I tried different methods, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452310/getting-the-next-record-into-view-from-database (this code is incomplete surely)

Comment: @Tomeksss another thing: in your `getPrevdata()` you have two lines out of order. you called `c.moveToPrevious();` and then `String data1 = c.getString(1);`. shouldn't it be the other way around? you first call `String data1 = c.getString(1);` and THEN you call `c.moveToPrevious();` ???? because first time you call `getPrevdata()` cursor is at position 0. your code will first move cursor to -1 and then call `getString()` at position -1. Try to switch those two lines in both getPrevdata and getNextdata

Comment: @Tomeksss if that still does not work, can you tell us which line of the code is breaking? on LogCat, it says, `in.ekonomia.android.przyslowiaarabskie.Galeria.onCreate(Galeria.java:26)` but which line is that in your code? (on stack overflow there are no numbers)